# How can I add a new line before a specific line (last line) in text file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Suppose I have a **diskpart** script file `disk1.txt` containing:

```
list vol
exit
```

and batch file which contains:

```
    @echo off
    pushd %~dp0
    diskpart /s disk1.txt
    set /p vol=enter number of the volume 
    echo sel vol %vol% > disk2.txt
    type disk1.txt >> disk2.txt
    diskpart /s disk2.txt
    del disk2.txt
    pause
```

Now I want to add a line in `disk2.txt` before the last line.

How can I add the new line before the last line?

And how can I add a new line before a specific line, i.e. before line 4 or line 3, or any other specified line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo batch code for inserting a line at a specific position within a text file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem A negative value inserts a line X lines before last line of source file.
rem A positive value inserts a line before line X from source file.
rem Value 0 assigned to InsertBeforeLine results in a copy of source file.

set "InsertBeforeLine=-1"

if %InsertBeforeLine% LSS 0 (
    set "LineCount=1"
    for /F "usebackq eol= delims=" %%L in ("disk1.txt") do set /A "LineCount+=1"
    set /A "InsertBeforeLine+=LineCount"
)

set "LineCount=1"
for /F "usebackq eol= delims=" %%L in ("disk1.txt") do (
    if %InsertBeforeLine% EQU !LineCount! echo Inserted line>>disk2.txt
    echo %%L>>disk2.txt
    set /A "LineCount+=1"
)

endlocal
```

Note: This simple batch code does not work for a source file containing lines with no characters or only whitespace characters. In other words each line in `disk1.txt` must contain at least 1 non whitespace character.

Comment: how can I replace the old 'disk2.txt' file with the modified 'disk2.txt' file?

Comment: The line `echo sel vol %vol% > disk2.txt` in your batch file replaces already an existing `disk2.txt` with a new file containing the text output by command __echo__. The batch code above appends the other lines from `disk1.txt` to `disk2.txt` with the additionally inserted line when used instead of `type disk1.txt >> disk2.txt`. Of course you can insert in my code as third line also `del "disk2.txt" 2>nul` to delete an existing `disk2.txt` before copying the lines. See also Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).